# Will the EventHandlers that are associated with a Timer still be there after Tick occurs?

Tags: c#, timer, event-handling

Let's say I tie an event handler to a `Timer`'s `Tick` event.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TickHandler);
myTimer.Start();
```

How long will the associated `EventHandler` stay tied to the `Timer`? Will it be removed when `Tick` occurs? Will it be removed when I do `myTimer.Stop()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handler will be there and will be fired every time `Tick` occurs. If you call `myTimer.Stop()` it will no longer `Tick` and so handler will not fire but it will still be there. If you want to call the haldner only once you can either remove it explicitly or stop the timer. It will be there untill you detach it using `myTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(TickHandler);` or your object is collected by garbage collector as told by [@rerun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122550/will-the-eventhandlers-that-are-associated-with-a-timer-still-be-there-after-tick/4122571#4122571).

Answer (score 2):

It will stay around until the object is disposed of or you remove the handler.

Comment: Until what object is disposed? The timer or the one with the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

The event handler will be associated until you detach it from the object, or the until the object is disposed.

detaching:

```
myTimer.Tick -= (TickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

It follows the rules as any .NET event. It will remain attached to the object until you remove it explicitly. Of course if the timer itself is destroyed then the handler will no longer be called.